# Hooking up many inputs to Arduino

Tags: arduino

I need help setting up a system with my Arduino and hooking up ~ 90 inputs to it. Here is the system I am envisioning:

- The Arduino is hooked up to a change/money insertion machine (like paying for a coke at a vending machine).
- When the customer inserts the appropriate amount of money, they can choose which machine they want to activate (like choosing different candy bars on a vending machine). There will be about ~90 choices.
- I want the Arduino to take this input and be able to signal to any individual machine out of the 90 machines to activate some process in that individual machine.
- How the system currently works is that each individual machine has its own money insertion mechanism that activates the process individually at each machine. I want to create a centralized payment system that knows about each individual machine.

My questions are the following:

- Is it possible to hook up 90 inputs the Arduino and then to send individual messages to each of the 90 inputs?
  (My research had lead me to [a shift register](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShiftOut), but it seems unlikely to be able to connect 90 individual inputs to the Arduino this way.
- Is there a part that connects to the Arduino that can accept money as change?

Comment: I was thinking of that when I was thinking of simple elevator algorithm and my idea was putting a different resistor to different inputs and check out for analog input voltage. Unfortunatelly, this mechanism fails with multiple inputs at a time.

Comment: But another idea is to find some IC with buffer - then you will read from IC using serial communication. This is how keyboards work.

Comment: What is an IC? Is it some buffers which will contain some buffer that can only be written to synchronously? I'm not too worried about shared state because most likely, multiple people paying money are doing it serially while waiting in a line

Comment: I assembled arduino just today. My friend used IC from wheel mouse to capture input from encoders (those things that do count rotation). You should take an IC from old keyboard. Or you can take an IC created with that exact purpose.

Comment: So far I vote you up and wish you luck. But I think you should post that on electronics.stackexchange.com. And also you should vote for creation of [Arduinos own stackexchange forum](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49538/arduino).

Comment: Even though there is no Arduino board, [this should be migrated](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), not closed!

Answer (score 6):

There are multiplexers that you can connect your arduino to, which increase its capacity for inputs:
[Arduino Playground Multiplexer Tutorial](http://playground.arduino.cc/learning/4051)

Sparkfun has a [prebuilt shield](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9832) which encapsulates the multiplexer IC, but it only gives you 48 inputs.

As for taking coins, a device called a coin acceptor can be found. There are a number of suppliers, including [Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11636).

There may be ways you can reduce the necessary inputs and/or outputs. For example, do you need 90 buttons, or could you use a 10 key pad, and give each item a two digit code?

Comment: The plan is to provide a keypad that allows number selections. When I say ~90 inputs I should 90 inputs and outputs. I want to be able to signal to each of the 90 machines individually. We are going to provide a keypad that allows you to choose one of the 90 machines. We will not have 90 buttons. Thanks for the response, I will check out the links.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to hook up more than one multiplexer shield to the arduino?

Comment: Near as I can tell, they are stackable. They note that the metal USB port on the Arduino may come into contact with pins on the board, so you can put some black tape or something on the top of the port. If you have 90 devices (motors, or even stepper motors), you can probably do this with just 19 outputs: connect all the negative poles of the motors in a row together, and all the positive poles in each column together, then switch each row and column with relays. You can turn on, say X=2, and Y=3, to run an individual motor; you just can't control more than one at once.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's entirely doable. A keyboard has 101 keys, and at least historically, was decoded by a chip much, much less powerful than the Arduino. Shift registers can be chained to allow large numbers of inputs and outputs, at the cost of read/write speed. There are also chips you can buy (such as the LM8330) that decode a matrix keypad for you, and are accessible over I2C, which only requires two pins. And a coin slot is electrically the same as a push-button, except it only toggles when a valid coin is inserted.